# Hidden Extension to Refresh Itself

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a notification extension that shows number of new notifications on itself.

How can i make my extension refresh itself in XX seconds when it is not shown so it can update its number?

I've tried this page: [Chrome extension refresh page when is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705200/chrome-extension-refresh-page-when-is-not-visible)
But it only works when it is visible (in that case, in else statement) I can't get it work when it is hidden. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this logic in to a [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), and then in that file start a loop using `setInterval` and run your code in that.